# Android, как правильно выбрать фотографию из галереи

Tags: java, android, изображения

Нужно выбрать фотку из галереи. Вот код, в котором при клике переходим в галерею:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
i.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(i, Constants.REQUEST);
```

Вот переопределение метода onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Bitmap img = null;
            if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                try {
                    img = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                circleImageView.setImageBitmap(img);
            }
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Все запускается, все хорошо, но при выборе фотки не возвращается в приложение и не ставит фотку в ImageView. Через логирование узнал, что очему то не запускается onActivityResult. Что делать ?

**UPDATE**

Все происходит в фрагменте. Я думал в этом и ошибка, но в методе onActivityResult в активности так же ничего не происходит.

Comment: Вот так пробовали: `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);`?

Comment: к сожаление не помогает (

Comment: А так: `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`?

Comment: такая же проблема. Оно почему то не возвращается в приложение... Возможно потому, что все происходит во фрагментах ? Или это не имеет значение ?

Comment: Возможно, у вас что-то не так в манифесте, в атрибуте android:launchMode у активити

Comment: А какие нужно иметь пермишины для этого ? В манифесте ничего не добавлял просто. Делал все, как написано здесь в статье http://androidturtorial.blogspot.com/2013/12/intent-startactivity-activity-service.html

Comment: Попробуйте вот это в манифест добавить: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Ничего не изменилось (

Comment: А если вызывать так: `getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, Constants.REQUEST);`?

Comment: все так же ( ничего

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы вызываете `startActivity` из фрагмента то `onActivityResult` нужно ловить в фрагменте, а если из `activity` то в `activity`

Пример рабочего кода (использовал в проекте):

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_AVATAR);
```

Далее onActivityResult:

```
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_AVATAR && data!=null){
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                // create file
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,null,null,null,null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                String path = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
                File file = new File(ImagePickUpUtil.getRealPathFromURI(this,selectedImage));
                ...
}
```

По просьбе ImagePickUpUtil:

```
public class ImagePickUpUtil {

        public static final int PICK_CODE = 100;
        /**
         * Detect the available intent and open a new dialog.
         *
         * @param context
         */
       public static void openMediaSelector(Activity context) {

            Intent camIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            Intent gallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            gallIntent.setType("image/*");

    // look for available intents
            List<ResolveInfo> info = new ArrayList<ResolveInfo>();
            List<Intent> yourIntentsList = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(camIntent, 0);
            for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
                final Intent finalIntent = new Intent(camIntent);
                finalIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                yourIntentsList.add(finalIntent);
                info.add(res);
            }

            List<ResolveInfo> listGall = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(gallIntent, 0);
            for (ResolveInfo res : listGall) {
                final Intent finalIntent = new Intent(gallIntent);
                finalIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                yourIntentsList.add(finalIntent);
                info.add(res);
            }

    // show available intents
            openDialog(context, yourIntentsList, info);
        }

        /**
         * Open a new dialog with the detected items.
         *
         * @param context
         * @param intents
         * @param activitiesInfo
         */
        private static void openDialog(final Activity context, final List<Intent> intents,
                                       List<ResolveInfo> activitiesInfo) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Выберите действие");
            dialog.setAdapter(buildAdapter(context, activitiesInfo),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Intent intent = intents.get(id);
                            context.startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CODE);
                        }
                    });

            dialog.setNeutralButton("Отмена",
                    new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            dialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Build the list of items to show using the intent_listview_row layout.
         *
         * @param context
         * @param activitiesInfo
         * @return
         */
        private static ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> buildAdapter(final Context context, final List<ResolveInfo> activitiesInfo) {
            return new ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo>(context, R.layout.intent_listview_row, R.id.title, activitiesInfo) {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    ResolveInfo res = activitiesInfo.get(position);
                    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                    image.setImageDrawable(res.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager()));
                    TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    textview.setText(res.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString());
                    return
                            view;
                }
            };
        }
    // =============================================================

        /**
         * Get absolute path of the file from it's uri
         *
         * @param context Context from your activity.
         * @param contentURI Uri of the file.
         * @return absolute path of the file
         */
        public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentURI) {
            String result = null;
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
                result = contentURI.getPath();
            } else {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                if(idx >= 0) {
                    result = cursor.getString(idx);
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static Bitmap scaleImageFile(File f) {
            try {
    // Decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 300;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                int scale = 1;
                while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE &&
                        o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                    scale *= 2;
                }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        // Storage Permissions
        private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
        private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        };

        /**
         * Checks if the app has permission to write to device storage
         *
         * If the app does not has permission then the user will be prompted to grant permissions
         *
         * @param activity
         */
        public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
            int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // We don't have permission so prompt the user
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        activity,
                        PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                        REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что значит "ImagePickUpUtil" в строке:
 File file = new File(ImagePickUpUtil.getRealPathFromURI(this,selectedImage));

Comment: @Samuliak Это класс, где он умеет парсить из uri реальный путь к файлу на устройстве

Comment: У меня почему то не находит данный класс, хочет, что бы его создали. В чем может быть проблема ??

Comment: @Samuliak данный класс нужно добавлять в проект, сейчас кину его в ответ

Comment: То есть нужно создать данный класс у себя в проекте ? Я думал, что это стандартный класс ... )

Comment: @Samuliak Нет, его нет в стандартных библиотеках, создайте его

Comment: Хотя все равно не работает!( Скорее всего из за того, что все происходит в эмуляторе ?? Просто другого объяснение тому, что не возвращается в активность я не знаю...

Answer (score 0):

Похожая проблема.
Удаление строки

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

из описания activity решило проблему